# Are there any interesting categories/objects whose products are isomorphic to themselves?

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, products

This was inspired from an exercise in Lawvere & Schanuel's Conceptual Mathematics.

It asks what objects in $\mathbf{Set}$ (finite sets), $\mathbf{S^\circlearrowleft}$ (endomaps in $\mathbf{Set}$), and $\mathbf{S^{\downarrow\downarrow}}$ (irreflexive graphs) are isomorphic to the product with themselves. I think the answers in these categories aren't too interesting (unless I missed some, let me know!).

In $\mathbf{Set}$ they are $\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{1}$

In $\mathbf{S^\circlearrowleft}$ they are again the empty set, and the one element set (loop)

In $\mathbf{S^{\downarrow\downarrow}}$ they are the empty graph, the "naked" dot (no arrows), and the loop

So, are there any interesting examples that arise, or are they all pretty trivial?

Comment: It would seem in a topos, any subobject of 1 satisfies the condition.  So, for example in the category of sheaves on $\mathbb{R}$, there are as many objects satisfying the condition as there are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: On the other hand, in the full category of all sets, any infinite set works.

Comment: Good point. I guess the construction of Z/Q qualifies as interesting :)

Comment: I guess you rather mean $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$. With which structure?

Comment: I meant $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ were interesting examples since they can be constructed from $\mathbb{N}$ as products, like Daniel mentioned. I didn't mean quotient structures, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, a fun example/exercise is to find a ring $R$ such that the free (left) $R$-modules $R$ and $R^{2}$ are isomorphic. (Note that such a ring must necessarily be noncommutative, since all commutative rings have the invariant basis property.) For such a ring $R$, the category of finitely generated free $R$-modules has precisely one isomorphism class.

Comment: There are non-obvious examples in the category of linear orders (with the [product order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_order)). For example, $\mathbb{Q}^2\approx\mathbb{Q}$. This [paper](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~gervin/cubeproblem.pdf) proves a product-related "cube property" for linear orders and mentions its analogue in other categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot answer the question whether the concept of an object isomorphic to the product with itself deserves to be regarded as interesting. However, there are "universal" examples.

1) Terminal objects.

A terminal object $T$ is one such that for each object $X$ there exists exactly one morphism $X \to T$. Examples are the one point set in $\mathbf{Set}$, the trivial group in the category of groups, ...

All terminal objects are isomorphic, and it is easy to see that $T \times T$ is again a terminal object (use the categorical definition of products).

2) In the category $\mathbf{SET}$ of all sets: Each infinite set.

This is a special feature of $\mathbf{SET}$. For example, for abelian group it is not true.

3) Infinite products.

Let $X$ be a any object and $A$ be an infinite set. Then $P = \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ with $X_\alpha = X$ has the property $P \times P \approx P$. This comes from fact that $A \times \{1,2\} \approx A$ in $\mathbf{SET}$.